# Correct way to generate Root CA, Server and Client certificates

Tags: ssl, rust, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, tls1.3

The certificates I generate with my code below are not working correctly with a Mutual TLS implementation of gRPC using Tonic.

Am guessing something is not correctly setup.

Uusing the `rcgen` crate.

This is how I generate the root:

```
let mut params = CertificateParams::default();

params.alg = &PKCS_ECDSA_P384_SHA384; 
params.key_pair = Some(KeyPair::generate(&PKCS_ECDSA_P384_SHA384)?);
params.key_identifier_method = KeyIdMethod::Sha384;

let mut dn = DistinguishedName::new(); 
dn.push( 
    DnType::CommonName, 
    DnValue::PrintableString("Test Root CA ECC".to_string()), 
); 
params.distinguished_name = dn;
params.is_ca = IsCa::Ca(BasicConstraints::Unconstrained);

params.not_before = OffsetDateTime::now_utc(); 
params.not_after = OffsetDateTime::now_utc() + Duration::days(365 * 10);

params.key_usages = vec![
    KeyUsagePurpose::KeyCertSign, 
    KeyUsagePurpose::CrlSign
];
let cert = Certificate::from_params(params)?;

let cert_pem = cert.serialize_pem(); 
let mut cert_file = fs::File::create("cert_root.pem")?;
cert_file.write_all(cert_pem.unwrap().as_bytes())?;

let private_key_pem = cert.serialize_private_key_pem(); 
let mut private_key_file = fs::File::create("cert_root.key")?;
private_key_file.write_all(private_key_pem.as_bytes())?;
```

The server:

```
let mut params = CertificateParams::default();

params.alg = &PKCS_ECDSA_P384_SHA384;
params.key_pair = Some(KeyPair::generate(&PKCS_ECDSA_P384_SHA384).unwrap()); 
params.key_identifier_method = KeyIdMethod::Sha384;

let mut dn = DistinguishedName::new();
dn.push( 
    DnType::CommonName, 
    DnValue::PrintableString("r.u.local".to_string()),
);
params.distinguished_name = dn;

params.subject_alt_names = vec![ 
    SanType::DnsName("localhost".to_string()),        
    SanType::IpAddress(
        std::net::IpAddr::V4(
            std::net::Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)
        )
    ),
    SanType::IpAddress(
        std::net::IpAddr::V6(
            std::net::Ipv6Addr::new( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, )
        )
    ),
];

params.not_before = OffsetDateTime::now_utc();
params.not_after = OffsetDateTime::now_utc() + Duration::days(365 * 1);

let cert = Certificate::from_params(params)?; 
let cert_signed = cert.serialize_pem_with_signer(&root_cert)?;
```

And the client:

```
let mut params = CertificateParams::default();

params.alg = &PKCS_ECDSA_P384_SHA384;
params.key_pair = Some(KeyPair::generate(&PKCS_ECDSA_P384_SHA384).unwrap());
params.key_identifier_method = KeyIdMethod::Sha384;

let mut dn = DistinguishedName::new();
params.distinguished_name = dn;

params.not_before = OffsetDateTime::now_utc();
params.not_after = OffsetDateTime::now_utc() + Duration::days(365 * 1);

let cert = Certificate::from_params(params)?;

let cert_signed = cert.serialize_pem_with_signer(&root_cert)?;
```

Do I need to use the ExtendedKeyUsagePurpose and set ClientAuth & ServerAuth?

Am I missing something else?

Comment: only people who make this standard know how

Comment: Please give a more specific error than *"are not working correctly"*. Also, in order to get help from people which know about certificates but not enough abut rust (like me) it would be helpful to provide the actually generated certificates, so that one can point out what might be wrong with the generated certificate. As to what key usage you might need see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68491/recommended-key-usage-for-a-client-certificate